# I can't set a gateway of last resort

Tags: cisco, routing, router, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I can't seem to get to set a gateway of last resort on a router. I want it to forward anything whom's ip address is not in the routing table to router HQ through interface s0/0/0 by doing the following:

```
Branch1#config t
Branch1(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 s0/0/0
```

When I check the routing table it doesn't appear there...

```
Branch1#sh ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route
Gateway of last resort is not set
     192.168.7.0/24 is variably subnetted, 8 subnets, 4 masks
C       192.168.7.64/27 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0.107
L       192.168.7.94/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0.107
C       192.168.7.144/28 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0.37
L       192.168.7.158/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0.37
C       192.168.7.160/28 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0.157
L       192.168.7.174/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0.157
C       192.168.7.244/30 is directly connected, Serial0/0/1
L       192.168.7.245/32 is directly connected, Serial0/0/1
```

Although it does appear in the running-config as

```
    ip classless 
    ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Serial0/0/0
```

The ip interface brief:

```
    Branch1#sh ip interface br
    Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol 
    GigabitEthernet0/0     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up 
    GigabitEthernet0/0.37  192.168.7.158   YES manual up                    up 
    GigabitEthernet0/0.107 192.168.7.94    YES manual up                    up 
    GigabitEthernet0/0.157 192.168.7.174   YES manual up                    up 
    GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
    Serial0/0/0            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up 
    Serial0/0/1            192.168.7.245   YES manual up                    up 
    Serial0/1/0            unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
    Serial0/1/1            unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
    Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is going to be that the interface is down. When an interface goes down, any routes that are pointed to the interface are withdrawn from the routing table, but they will reappear when the interface comes back up.

Comment: The interfaces are up already

Comment: Give us a `show ip interface brief` in your question. You do not have any routes attached to `S0/0/0`, meaning it is down or you have not assigned any addressing.

Comment: Sorry, added them.

Comment: You do not have IPv4 enabled on the interface, so you cannot route to the interface. For IPv4, the interface is down. You must either assign an IPv4 address, or you must use the `ip unnumbered <interface>` command on the interface to enable IPv4 for the interface.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue. In my case one of the interfaces was down. I have activated it and it solved the issue.

Step 1:

Initially, check your routing table

If you are enable mode, use

```
show ip interface brief
```

If you are in configuration mode, use

`do show ip int bri`  ( here **do** is added )

Step 2:

Check the topology of your network and set the ip address accordingly.

1. interface (interface name)

`int g0/2` ( interface is gi 0/2)

2. set ip address

`ip address 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0`

NOTE: use the ip addresses, interface related to your topology

Comment: The OP was asking about a *serial* interface which works numbered or unnumbered - as long as IP has been activated on it. Otoh, an Ethernet interface *requires* an IP address as a router interface.